# MySQL, remove partial data from a field

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a MEDIUMTEXT column. Many records contain a value in that field with a value like "WordA WordB || RandomWords"
i would like to remove " || RandomWords" so the value will be "WordA WordB". How can I do that? In other words I need to search for the "||" characters and delete all that comes after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE t SET col=SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'||',1)
```

Assuming a single || per row